# GnuPG: verifying the sender

Tags: privacy, pgp, gnupg

A person emailed me his PGP signature. When I compared it to the signature from the PGP server, it is much shorter not matching at all. I use the version 1.4.9.

1. Why is the signature so short?
2. Why does it not match the server?
3. What is the signature of about 100 bits' encryption?

   -----BEGIN PGP SIGNATURE-----
   Version: GnuPG v1.4.7 (NetBSD)

   iD8DBQBKl0BmzbodwsP3RI0RAqQwAKCsP�覃ᝋꜴ鉰਍�
   1TEDKNU8/04JTQRbHotaDd0=
   =Ju5N
   -----END PGP SIGNATURE-----

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you might be confusing the signature with the public key -- a PGP signature is typically at the bottom of the message it is attached to, and depends on the message and the keypair used to sign it.  What you pull off the server is probably the public part of the user's keypair.

What I think you want is to [verify](http://www.gnupg.org/gph/en/manual/x135.html) the signature using GnuPG.